# iOS - What is the control that the Teamviewer app is using called?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm using the Teamviewer app for iOS and I notice that they use some-sort of a loading pop-up view while you wait to connect to your computer

[image]

Also, when you're about to close the connection, another sort of a popup view appears with a "Close" button.

[image]

Are there controls like these included in cocoa touch? If not, how was it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first appears to be an ordinary `UIView` styled to look like a `UIAlertView` with `UIActivityIndicatorView`, `UILabel` and `UIButton` subviews. The second looks like a `UIActionSheet`.

There is no standard system way of presenting a custom alert in Cocoa. You could achieve a similar effect with `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` or roll your own solution from the ground up, but then you'd have to manage screen rotation, window level, etc. You may want to take a look at [ios-custom-alertview](https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't know about the UIActionSheet until now, and it seems that's the one for the second. For the first one, did they happen to present it modally? Since I couldn't interact with the buttons on the background when it appeared

Comment: I can't tell exactly how they accomplished that alert without looking at their code :) Added a link to the answer that may help you.

Comment: I'd also encourage you to take a look at the [UIKit User Interface Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/) on Apple's developer site for more info about basic controls.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Definitely helps!